# Cloud Storage based on RAM

Tags: cloud, storage, couchbase, ram

You have 32 Gigabytes of RAM on your machine and need to store 100 million documents (~40 Gigabytes).  The documents are in the 2 following document formats.  Describe 3 or more ways you would accomplish this.

This is a question given in a questionnaire for cloud engineer interview and I am unsure how to answer the question.

Comment: This feels a lot like a "do my homework" question. Your questions says "The documents are in the 2 following document formats" but you don't list any information about the formats.

Comment: Your solutions must be done with couchbase? or other products?

Answer (score 0):

1. Mount a remote cloud storage using fuse drivers (blobfuse, s3fs).
2. Mount a remote block store (e.g EBS).
3. Mount a remote filesystem like  (AWS EFS, GFS).
4. Store in a key value store like DDB, CosmosDB.
5. If the data can be compressed, store it in the ram with compression.